# XChat keep IRC text highlighted after close

Tags: irc, xchat

I want to keep XChat text highlighted after close also I want to keep the whole log from the channel I logged to appear when opening the channel.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the latter, but you can simply turn on xchat's own logging in 'settings -> preferences -> logging' to get it to log and keep logs for everything.